# Several modal windows with jQuery simplemodal plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, simplemodal

Is it possible?

For example my first modal window appended to 'body' and has z-index: 1002

if I'm trying in FireBug open new modal window (appended to 'body' or existed modal window) with z-index more then 1002. I've just see 'false' as the result

for example:

```
$.modal('<h1>First modal</h1>');
```

and then in console

```
$.modal('<h1>Next modal</h1>', {zIndex: 1002+, appendTo: 'body' or 'First modal'})
```

jQuery 1.4.2, jquery.simplemodal-1.3.5

Comment: 'body' or 'First modal' - it's not in my code ) in code only one of options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleModal only supports one modal open at a time.

You can swap out content of an open modal or close and re-open a new one.